# Sonar Portfolio is not showing configured projects, message portfolio has no projects, or none of associated projects has lines of code

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have created a portfolio and added few applications to portfolio but when i choose portfolio in the sonar dashboard it shows the below message even though i have added few projects to it and there were no background tasks or analysis related data after sonar analysis on one of the project.
Message: 
This portfolio is empty.
This portfolio has no projects, or none of associated projects has lines of code.

We have followed the below link to configure a portfolio.
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Portfolios+and+Applications

Created a Portfolio and few projects the portfolio
Project selection mode: Manual
Sonar Version: 6.7.4 LTS 
Enterprise Edition
Issue: i Could not see the projects which i have added to portfolio under Sonar portfolio section

Can someone please point me to the right configuration steps or help me with the resolution.

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve for this problem? I'm encountering it as well. I see reference in the documentation to a "Computation" that needs to be run which kicks off a Background Task to update the dashboard but apparently submitting a new project scan does not qualify. I feel like this could be permissions related - I'm an admin of the portfolio which is not executing but do not have global admin rights. Perhaps this computation needs to be initiated at the global admin level?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured this out and wanted to share with anyone else who stumbles across this problem. The issue here is that the SonarQube version being used by the OP is 6.7 (similar to me) and the documentation he linked to is for the latest version of SonarQube (7.3 as of this writing).

The documentation for 6.7 is located [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE67/Documentation) and navigating to the equivalent [Configuring Portfolios and Applications](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE67/Configuring+Portfolios+and+Applications) page includes the following required command be run in order to execute the Portfolio Calculation task in previous versions of SonarQube:

> Calculation Calculation must be triggered manually each time a
>   Portfolio structure is modified. Portfolios should also be recomputed
>   on a regular basis to keep them up to date with the most recent
>   project quality snapshots. Portfolio are computed with the SonarQube
>   Scanner.
>
> To compute all your Portfolio, run the following command (credentials
>   from a user with "Administer System" or "Execute Analysis" permission
>   is required):
>
> ```
> sonar-scanner views -Dsonar.login=<token>
> or
> sonar-scanner views -Dsonar.login=<login> -Dsonar.password=<pwd>
> ```

So when using SQ 6.7, without running that `sonar-scanner views` command in your build plan, only the `Project Analysis` task will run and your Portfolios will never be updated. Running this `views` command appears to run the `Portfolio Calculation` task for all Portfolios on the SQ Server which in turn will update the UI for each entry.